# bat file - delete directory contents except specific file and specific subfolder

Tags: batch-file

I have a directory 'help' where a web application is deployed. It contains a number of files at the root level and a number of sub folders.

I'd like to run a bat file (from outside the directory) which deletes everything within the directory except for the web.config file and a folder called 'log'.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, but what you can do is copy the file and folder in a different location, delete the entire content of the folder, then restore the file and folder.

Comment: I thought this would be the case. Thanks